# Whitespace Appears around Background Image

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I have the following React snippet:

```
const CategoryItem = ({ imageUrl, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className='category-container'>
      <div
        className='category-container__bg'
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}
      ></div>
      <div className='category-container__body'>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>Shop Now</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and styled as follows using Sass:

```
.category-container {
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  height: 25rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;

  &__bg {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1.5s ease;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__body {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 7rem;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 0 1.5625rem;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;

    h2 {
      color: #4a4a4a;
      font-size: 1.375rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0 0.375rem 0;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;

    .category-container__bg {
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }

    .category-container__body {
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
  }
}
```

Although I am using `background-size: cover`, I am getting a weird whitespace around the background image (shown in the screenshot below). I have tried playing with the border as this sometimes fixes the issue, but it is not working for this case.

Are there any workarounds for this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have margin somewhere? Inspect every element with the den tools to find this

Comment: @cloned no I do not have any margins I have checked that, what is weird is that this whitespace does not appear when I run the web app on Mozilla Firefox, it only appears on Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: does changing the margin or the border width on ```.category-container``` solve the issue?
for example ```margin: 11px``` or ```border: 8px solid #000;```

Comment: Does the white line come and go as you zoom?

Comment: @SamerAlkhatib, I have tried playing with the `border-width` and it is a trial and error process, the only value that worked for me was actually as you said `8px`. Changing the `margin` does not do anything. The problem is that my design requires the `border-width` to be `5px`.

Comment: @AHaworth, no it is there on 100% of zoom level, which surprised me.

Comment: So it’s there always, even on all high zoom levels?

Comment: @AHaworth, The whitespace appears on all Chromium-based browsers (does not appear on Mozilla Firefox). It disappears for some zoom levels and appears on others (for example, if the `border-width` is below `8px` it shows on nearly all zoom levels, however, if it is above that value, it shows on some zoom levels and disappears on other zoom levels).

Comment: This phenomenon is caused by a sort of rounding error effect when the system is trying to deal with matching part pixels to the multiple screen pixels that may make up one CSS pixel on modern screens.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various workarounds involving pseudo before elements of slightly larger size etc.

The simplest method in this particular case seems to be to set the background color of the parent element.

```css
.category-container {
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid #0008;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  height: 25rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

.category-container__bg {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
}

.category-container__body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 7rem;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 0 1.5625rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.category-container h2 {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0.375rem 0;
}

.category-container p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class='category-container'>
  <div class='category-container__bg'></div>
  <div class='category-container__body'>
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <p>Shop Now</p>
  </div>
</div>
```